# Django , simple_captcha, how to access hashed key

Tags: python, django, captcha

how can I access captcha's hashed key inside my view? I tried using _key, _value, image_and_audio but I get attribute error every time.
and, what I do not understand, is that in simple captcha, _key and _value can only be used inside two functions. how is that possible? and how can I use them outside those functions?
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Show your view code please

Comment: my problem is not exactly with the view, my main problem is accessing _key value. I have created a CaptchaField in my login form